# How to make my search recursive for MIT 6001x course

Tags: python, algorithm, edx

Programming Using Python, and I have a task to recursively write search algorithm that can locate any given letter in any given string. However, even though my code gets the job done without any iteration, the grader still complains it isn't recursive.
How can I make this more recursive to achieve the same purpose?

Here's my code:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string
    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    l = len(astr)//2
    if astr[l] != astr[0]:
        if astr[l] > char:
            astr = astr[:l]        
        else:
            astr = astr[l:]
    else:
        if astr[l] == char:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return isin(char, astr)
```

Comment: If you fix your spelling, it is recursive. Are you sure you're supposed to return a bool and not the index of where the character is found? Also, what does alphabetized mean, do you mean each character is sorted in alphabetical order? I think you do have some logic errors though, have you tested your function?

Comment: in recursive version you should run the same function but with shorter data/string - ie. `def isIn(char, aStr): ... isIn(char, aStr[:l]) ... isIn(char, aStr[l:])...`

Comment: @furas the code as it stands does do that because it reassigns `astr` to be shorter and then recurses on the correct half. So it makes no sense to say this function isn't recursive. Whether it is correct or not is another question, I have a feeling that the outer else maybe should have been for the inner if

Comment: @Dan it do this but in so hidden way so it is hard to say that it is recursion :) And it can be problem for grader.

Comment: @Dan I Alphabetized means alphabetic order. I have tested the function and it works fine. And the was no complaint as to it's correctness, but of its recursiveness.

Comment: @furas can you suggest a way to make the recursive call more visible for the grader?

Comment: @furas it is not hidden at all. It recurses at the end, exactly where it should. I think the problem here is the grader, or maybe the OPs understanding of what the grader's complaint was. There is no such thing as making it *more* recursive.

Comment: @TosinCoker I think you should speak with your grader as it sounds like either you have misunderstood their complaint or they have misunderstood your code. There is no such thing as *more recursive*. You could clean up your base cases, but in terms of the recursion, aside from your typos which you should really fix in your question, you are calling the same function on the correct substring so their can be no complaint about using recursion here. I highly recommend you revert to your grader to better understand the complaint.

Comment: @Dan "more recursive" doesn't mean it works in different way but it looks more like examples in books which grader use to learn it - it has stop conditions at start and later recursion step. For grader it can be more important if it looks like examples in books then if it works correctly. If it doesn't look perfectly like in books then grader may treat it as "less recursive" or "not recursive"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two elements in recursion:

- first you check it for special chases like empty string or string with length 1 (stop condition)
- next you run the same function with shorter strings

Code:

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string
    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    l = len(aStr)

    # special cases - stop condition

    if l == 0:
        return False

    if l == 1:
        return char == aStr[0]

    # recursion for shorter strings

    l = l//2

    return isIn(char, aStr[:l]) or isIn(char, aStr[l:])
```

Tests:

```
print( isIn('c', '') ,   isIn('c', '') == False)

print( isIn('c', 'a'),   isIn('c', 'a') == False )
print( isIn('c', 'e'),   isIn('c', 'e') == False )
print( isIn('c', 'c'),   isIn('c', 'c') == True )

print( isIn('c', 'ab'),  isIn('c', 'ab') == False )
print( isIn('c', 'de'),  isIn('c', 'de') == False )

print( isIn('c', 'abc'), isIn('c', 'abc') == True )
print( isIn('c', 'cde'), isIn('c', 'cde') == True )
```

---

**EDIT:** special cases you can write also shorter

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
    '''
    char: a single character
    aStr: an alphabetized string
    returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
    '''
    l = len(aStr)

    # special cases - stop condition

    if l < 2:
        return char == aStr

    # recursion for shorter strings

    l = l//2

    return isIn(char, aStr[:l]) or isIn(char, aStr[l:])
```

---

**EDIT:** as @Dan mentioned in comment it can be more effective - log(n) - with `if/else` instead of `or` and it can still look "recursive"

```
    # recursion for shorter strings

    l = l//2

    if char < aStr[l]
        return isIn(char, aStr[:l])
    else:
        return isIn(char, aStr[l:])
```

Comment: `isIn(char, aStr[:l]) or isIn(char, aStr[l:]) ` isn't that quite inefficient since you are recursing fully on a branch you know doesn't contain the answer thus losing the log(n) runtime?

Comment: @Dan I tried to create code which looks more recursive - not code which work more effective :) If I start make it more effective then I male function without recursion :) But yes, using `if/else` instead of `or` it could be more effective.

Comment: I think I agree with @Dan, wouldn't it be more efficient if we did pick the right half to recurse on? I will try to sell that edited part with if/else statement to the grader.